# Why is one of the css styles not applied? background image gives 404

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, web-frontend

I have Django-project, which include CSS and HTML files, but one of the CSS styles not showing up.
I started my HTML with:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'images/custom.css' %}">
```

Also in **settings.py** there is line:
`STATIC_URL = "static/"`

HTML:

```HTML
<div class="container">
  <div class="contact-container">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```CSS
.container {
  background  : #0000;
  font-family : 'Istok Web', 'Nanum Myeongjo', 'Roboto', 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;
}

.contact-container {
  background-image      : url('images/aaa.jpg');
  background-attachment : fixed;
  background-size       : cover;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Style container is working correctly, but contact-container not showing up.

Comment: first step : look at your browser inspector... ;)

Comment: @MisterJojo I have a 'failed to load resourse: the server responded with status of 404'. But why? My picture my picture is in the folder main/static/images and CSS also in main/static/images

Comment: try `url('/static/images/aaa.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons this could be happening.

1. your settings.py has this exactly?: `**STATIC_URL = "static/"**`
   I've never seen the asterisks before. This is how I usually setup static files within settings.py:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   ]

   STATIC_URL = 'static/'

   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
   ]
   ```
2. How are you confirming that the container styling is working? Bootstrap has a class called `container`, so you might be pulling those styles
3. Are you putting your .css files within the `images/` directory? Is that where it actually is? I usually keep mine in `static/css/main.css`
4. Check the dev tools (right click -> inspect). In the terminal at the bottom you may see some errors. Also, if you are in the dev tools, navigate to the network tab, and refresh, you should be able to see the styles sheets loading (or not). This can be a good indicator as to if the stylesheet is loading. If so, it may show you some potential errors. Below you can see where my .css file is loading within the network tab:

[image]

5. You might have the static directory in the wrong place. This is where I keep mine:

[image]